# Is there a way to ignore certain suggested intellisense namespaces in Rider when typing code?

Tags: c#, rider

When typing C# code in JetBrains Rider, it gives a list of 'using' namespace suggestions. For example, typing 'List' will show a number of suggested 'using' namespaces it can add, like 'List<> (in System.Collections.Generic)'.

The annoying thing is, often the top suggestion is a namespace from a third-party library that you will never care about. Like typing 'Assert' will suggest using ModestTree from Zenject, something I will never need.

It's even so bad that I will already have a 'using' namespace for 'Assert' in my current class (in this case: using NUnit.Framework), and it will STILL suggest using the ModestTree as the top entry.

Is there any way to specify namespaces for a project that I will never want to use, and therefore not have them show up in the autocomplete suggestion? Perhaps a plugin?

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have a look [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Code_Analysis__Configuring_Warnings.html)

`Inspection [name of inspection] | Disable once with comment | Disable and restore with comment` — this option inserts a pair of comments before and after the issue - ReSharper disable [inspection id] and ReSharper restore [inspection id]. These comments suppress the inspection for all corresponding issues between them.
You can then move these comments to other places in the file so that several issues of this type are suppressed. For example, this can be useful to suppress the 'redundant namespace' inspection if you want to keep several unused namespace imports.

If it doesn't help, you can ask for help [here](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new)

Comment: It's not about ignoring the actual 'using ...' code, it's just about the code completion popup you get when typing. I added a screenshot to clarify.

Comment: @void_Foo seems like there is no option for your needs. What can partially solve your issue is turning off "Show import items in basic completion" in "File| Settings | Editor | General | Code Completion". After it, Rider won't suggest non-imported symbols in the completion.

Comment: Ha! Turns out there is a way, was able to figure it out thanks to your tip. In Settings | Editor | General | Auto Import you can specify a list of types / namespaces to ignore. I added 'ModestTree.*' to the list and it works. See also https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Coding_Assistance__Code_Completion__Type_Name.html. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

*(Since the currently accepted answer isn't the actual solution and not everyone bothers to read the comments, I'll add the answer here. It is based on OP's own comment)*

There is a setting in Rider under `Settings | Editor | General | Auto Import` that controls this.

It's usage is described in [the help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Coding_Assistance__Code_Completion__Type_Name.html#exclude-items-from-completion-suggestions), but in a nutshell you just add the namespaces/types to ignore to that list and they will never be suggested. You need to use wildcards to match partial names (such as entire namespaces)

For example, to exclude everything under the `DocumentFormats.` namespace, specify `DocumentFormats.*`.

[image: Screenshot of the setting]